# Convert float to int and leave nulls

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe, I want to convert values in column 'b' to integer

```
    a   b       c
0   1   NaN     3
1   5   7200.0  20
2   5   580.0   20
```

The following code is throwing exception 
"ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer"

```
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(int)
```

How do i convert only floats to int and leave the nulls as is?

Comment: Can I ask why? Looks ugly? integer array can't have `NaN`

Comment: I get you, so I should first replace NaN as 0 and then convert the column to int?

Comment: If you really want, 0, -1 or something you can distinguish

Comment: Depending on what you need, an other solution would be to filter out the rows with NaN to keep only the valid ones, with something like that : `df.dropna().astype(np.int64)`

Comment: Thank you Jeon and Jadsq

Comment: I beieve Pandas will have to convert the column to object dtype in order to mix integers and null/nan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.NaN` is a floating point only kind of thing, so it has to be removed in order to create an integer pd.Series. Jeon's suggestion work's great If 0 isn't a valid value in `df['b']`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 5, 5], 'b': [np.NaN, 7200.0, 580.0], 'c': [3, 20, 20]})
print(df, '\n\n')

df['b'] = np.nan_to_num(df['b']).astype(int)

print(df)
```

if there are valid 0's, then you could first replace them all with some unique value (e.g., -999999999), the the conversion above, and then replace these unique values with 0's.

Either way, you have to remember that you have 0's where there were once NaNs. You will need to be careful to filter these out when doing various numerical analyses (e.g., mean, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

When your series contains floats and nan's and you want to convert to integers, you will get an error when you do try to convert your float to a numpy integer, because there are na values.

**DON'T DO:**

```
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(int)
```

**From pandas >= 0.24 there is now a built-in pandas integer. This does allow integer nan's. Notice the capital in `'Int64'`. This is the pandas integer, instead of the numpy integer.**

**SO, DO THIS:**

```
df['b'] = df['b'].astype('Int64')
```

More info on pandas integer na values:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions

Comment: Int64, while supporting nulls in Pandas, it cannot be converted into PySpark dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer as TSeymour, but now using Panda's fillna:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 5, 5], 'b': [np.NaN, 7200.0, 580.0], 'c': [3, 20, 20]})
print(df, '\n\n')

df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
   a       b   c
0  1     NaN   3
1  5  7200.0  20
2  5   580.0  20 


   a     b   c
0  1     0   3
1  5  7200  20
2  5   580  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the variable values that are not NaN using the pandas [notnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html?highlight=notnull#pandas.DataFrame.notnull) function. Then, assign those variables to type int using [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function:

`df[df[0].notnull()] = df[df[0].notnull()].astype(int)`

I used the index number to make this solution more general. Of course, you can always specify using the column name like this: `df['name_of_column']`

Comment: This gives you the thing you asked for. Of course, if you want an all-integer DataFrame, as you discussed in the question comments, you won't apply this solution.